Why SpringBoot3 can not start EnableCamundaRestClient
When I use SpringBoot3.2.5 to integerate the Camunda but it failed, But When I use SpringBoot 2.6.4, it can work normally, Any suggestion is welcomed ~ Thanks
Below is the part of pom.xml I used
    <spring-boot.version>3.2.5</spring-boot.version>
    ...... 
    <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.camunda.community.rest</groupId>
       <artifactId>camunda-platform-7-rest-client-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>                
       <version>7.17.2</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-external-task-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.0</version>
    </dependency>


The startup Java application is as follows
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableCamundaRestClient 
public class ExternalTaskStarterJavaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExternalTaskStarterJavaApplication.class, args);
    }
}

I have tried to replaced <spring-boot.version>3.2.5</spring-boot.version> with <spring-boot.version>2.6.4</spring-boot.version>, it can work

try change your camunda dependency change version from 7.17.2 to  7.19.1 , I guess Spring Boot 3.x support Jakarta (Jakarta EE 10 ) not javax (Java EE 8). ( https://camunda.com/blog/2023/06/camunda-platform-7-road-to-jakarta-ee-10/ ) ,

From time to time we have incompatible changes in the spring-boot ecosystem (jdk version, javax/jakarta, web, ...) which require specialized updates in camunda/camunda-spring-boot as well.
That's why having a look at the compatibility matrix for camuna-spring-boot is crucial when choosing the correct dependencies.
In your case: 7.21.0 is the first CE version that is officially compatible with spring boot 3.2.x.
